# Get a string out of a string of dash-separated values

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a table that looks like this, (row 1 acts solely as titles):

```
 |----------A----------|---------B--------|--------C---------|---------D--------|
1|  String of Strings  |     Thing  1     |     Thing  2     |     Thing  3     |
 |---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
2|   q1-22ll-o7kp-e... |         q1       |       22ll       |     ??????       |
 |---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Using [this](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/06/01/split-text-string-excel/) guide, I've been able to successfully fill in cells B2 and C2:

B2: `=LEFT(A2, SEARCH("-",A2,1)-1)`

C2: `=MID(A2, SEARCH("-",A2) + 1, SEARCH("-",A2,SEARCH("-",A2)+1) - SEARCH("-",A2) - 1)`

I'm trying to understand the pattern for D2, though. I don't fully grasp what C2 is doing -- how would I build upon C2's formula so that I can get the *third* thing in my String of Strings?

I figure once I see the pattern for D2, I'll be able to continue going for E2, F2, etc.

I'm hoping to find a solution that works on either Google Sheets or Excel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With data in **A2**, in **B2** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"-",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999))
```

and copy across:

[image]

Comment: This is witchcraft to me but it works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: @PercentSharp  Glad to help!  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

In Google Sheets you can use [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136) in `B2` and it will extend the result to the cells on it's right:

```
=SPLIT(A2, "-")
```

For each individual part you can use `INDEX` :

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A2, "-"), , 1)
=INDEX(SPLIT(A2, "-"), , 2)
...
```

For the last 2 items independent of index:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2, ".*-(.*)-")
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2, ".*-(.*)")
```

Comment: Thanks for this crafty workaround, but I'm trying to have each row 2 formula be independently sufficient for use elsewhere in my workbook ^^.

Comment: This solution only works on [tag:google-spreadsheet] the OP just edited the question to specify that they are hopping for a solution that works on excel too.

Comment: @Rubén "**either** Google Sheets or Excel."

Comment: To be fair, I am platform-agnostic (used 'either/or' in edit)-- Slai's solution is helpful too as I don't mind doing my number crunching on either platform.

Comment: @PercentSharp subtle but important difference :) . I'm not sure if "either" instead of "and" could make this question to be considered too broad.

Comment: c'est la vie I guess considering we found a solution for both platforms within 12 minutes :). Thanks for the nuance though, it's important to keep things moderated.

Answer (score 0):

While `B2`'s formula uses straight-forward `LEFT`, `C2`'s formula is a bit more complicated and uses the function `MID(text, start_num, num_chars)`:

- `text` is obviously the input cell = `A2`
- `start_num` is the index that the output will start from, In this case,  `SEARCH("-",A2) + 1`, which is one character after the first `-`.
- `num_chars` is the number of characters that the output will contain. That's the tricky part! It actually calculates the number of characters between the first `-` and the second `-` by subtracting the first dash's index from the second dash's index.

This isn't the best method to recursively solve this problem, but I do believe it's important to understand every code, in order to write an optimal code next time.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it makes sense. This was mostly a copy + paste from the help article I linked, but I see how it could get very bloated very quickly.